# How to run the dag less than 1 minute intervals

Tags: airflow

The dags set in 1 minute interval time, but we need to set up the dags in 30 seconds intervals. Is there any way to achieve this in Airflow?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [schedule_interval documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.1/scheduler.html#dag-runs), you have two choices:

- **preset**: The minimum period is hourly
- **cron expression**: The [standard cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression) expression doesn't handle seconds

So achieve this with Airflow schedule interval is not possible. But you can handle it in your code. You can for exemple create 2 DAGs for the same schedule interval, and for one DAG wait the second 30 to run the code.